# Unable to execute Unix command through Java code

Tags: java, unix

```
case "BVT Tool":
    System.out.println("Inside BVT Tool");
    try {
        String[] command1 = new String[] {"mv $FileName /bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/"};
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("execption is :"+ e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
```

I'm unable to execute the Unix command. It's showing the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program mv $FileName /bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/":
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Reimeus on most points, but I want to point out that there reason you're getting this particular error message is a crosscontamination between 2 of the overloaded versions of exec:

```
String command1 = "mv $FileName /bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```

Would work - it's allowed to specify the command and its parameters in one String [if you use the overloaded version that expects a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] command1 = new String[] {"mv", "$FileName", "/bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```

would work too, because it uses the [the exec version expecting a String array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).  That version expects the command and its parameters in separate Strings

Please note that I here assume that `$Filename` is actually the name of the file, so no shell-based substitution will take place.

EDIT: if `FileName` is a variable name as you seem to suggest elsewhere in the comments, try

```
String[] command1 = new String[] {"mv", FileName, "/bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/"};
```

But : with [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) you could just do

```
FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(new File(FileName), new File("/bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/") , true);
```

[JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

which is

1. totally portable between Mac, Windows and Linux (your version won't work on Windows)
2. is faster because it doesn't need to spawn an external process
3. gives you more information when something goes wrong.

Comment: I tried but its throwing this exception:  execption is :java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mv": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: What does `which mv` return?  What Unix derivative are you using?

Comment: I don't know enough about AIX to know where it stores mv, that's why I suggested the command `which mv`, that will give you the full path to mv, which you can give as the first parameter to exec.  However, in my opinion you should really have a look at the Commons IO based solution, for the reasons laid out in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `Runtime.exec` is a very antiquated approach for running a command,

The complete `String` is being interpreted as the executable command. You need to use individual tokens in the `String` array. In addition you need to 
use a shell to interpret the `$FileName` variable

```
String[] command1 = {"bash", "-c", "mv", "$FileName", "/bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/"};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably be using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). The command you have is "mv" the rest should be arguments,

```
// I'm not sure about $FileName, that's probably meant to be a shell replace
// and here there is no shell.
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mv", 
    System.getenv("FileName"), "/bgw/feeds/ibs/incoming/");
```

Comment: Actually FileName is a variable which takes the input from a textbox which contain the file name.